# Block search engine from indexing Currency Words as content keywords

Tags: seo, google-search-console, googlebot, keywords, google-keyword-tool

I have one website with currency converter on it and Google WMT is considering the currency words as Content keywords. Is there anyway to block search engine from indexing this Currency Words like "Dollar, pound and all that". I am new in this and any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you worried about it because you see those words appearing in the "Content Keywords" report in Google Webmaster Tools?

Comment: Yes and I want to get rid of those keywords. Is it possible to prevent this by embedding that currency converter in iframe and blocking it from indexing?

Comment: The Google Content Keyword list is a junk list. Pay more attention to how people find your site. Of the 40 so-called keywords in almost 3 years, not one of them is how anyone has ever found my site. Do not worry about this list. Pay attention to how people find your site. Trust me.